# Can we put more than one meta tag in a single page website?

Tags: seo, meta-tags, single-page-application

I have a one page website, but it has "about us" "contact us", "services", "forum", etc... so I am little confused on how I should write the meta tags for it. Should I write only one meta tag for it because it has only one page, or should I put more than one meta tag, and if I write more than one meta tag, can I put more than one meta tag in a page?

What should I write if I had to put just one meta tag, given that it contains several sections? I mean with just one meta tag there would be problem in ranking for each section, right?

Comment: Why don't you have individual pages for about us, Contact us, Services and Forum?

Comment: Whilst your site might be "one page" (ie. no full page refresh), do you not manipulate the URL in any way when users navigate to different sections? Are you loading the section content using AJAX or do you literally just have one big static page?

Comment: What **meta** tag are you referring to? There are many types. Duplicate meta tags of a particular type (such as description which is against the HTML5 spec) are a bad idea, which one will win out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29647752/what-happens-if-i-accidentally-duplicate-a-meta-tag-in-my-head

Comment: According to Matt Cutts, Google is not valued any meta tags for any page.

Answer (score 4):

The downside of a single page website is the SEO aspect. You are not allowed to use multiple META's for the same thing (multiple 'description' doesn't work).

This is the point where you have to reconsider how you want to proceed. Is it a simple personal website which doesn't have a attract too many people? Then this is fine.

If SEO is important, you could make seperate urls (`/contact`, `/about-us`, `/services`) and make those work.
Then load the remainder of the website via javascript and use techniques like `window.pushState` to change the url to the proper one.

There is plenty of documentation about this, a simple googlesearch (`how to SEO a one page site`):
http://www.awwwards.com/seo-tricks-for-one-page-websites.html
http://searchengineland.com/single-page-websites-seo-182506
http://codeboxr.com/blogs/is-single-page-one-page-website-bad-for-seo

Answer (score 2):

Yes! If you use one meta tag for different sections in a single page, it might affect your ranking for the section based keywords.

Meta tags are the easiest way to tell about your web page to Search Engines. If you have multiple meta tags like `<title>`, `<description>` in a single page it will confuse the Bot to consider which meta tags should be used in SERP and finally it will select the more appropriate one based on the page content Or it will select the first tag.
So you should not use same meta tags multiple times in a single page.

1. You can smartly mention about your page in your `<title>` and `<description>` like `<About us|Contact us|Services|Forum>`
2. The best practice is using individual pages for "About us", "Contact us","Services", "Forum". It will be more user friendly and it is the best way in SEO perspective.

*For example:*

If you do some service and If you have an individual page for that, you can write more content specifically about that service and you can use meta tags in that page. So users will like that page and Search Engines too.
But it's not possible if you have a single page with bunch of contents about different sections and having one meta tag for all these sections.

Comment: In support of not having multiple **description** meta tags. Not only does it confuse the bot, HTML5 spec says there should only be one, so a bot that selects only the first one or the last one is well within its rights to ignore all the rest: http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#standard-metadata-names